# Ajax Contact Form, jQuery & PHP - NO special characters, not displaying

Tags: php, jquery

I'm having problems with the php contact form. It was sending e-mails with all Information (normal letters) but without special like example - óżćąę. It cut them for good like "król" "krl" itp. I want to display a success message with special letters via e-mail. In my opinion its something wrong with $headers. Don't know what's wrong any help appreciated. Regards!

Link to Contact Form [Click](https://www.sanwebe.com/2014/04/ajax-contact-form-attachment-jquery-php)

Contact_me.php

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
$to_email       = "email@gmail.com"; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here
$from_email     = "noreply@YOUR-DOMAIN.com"; //From email address (eg: no-reply@YOUR-DOMAIN.com)

//check if its an ajax request, exit if not
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
        'type'=>'error',
        'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
    ));
    die($output); //exit script outputting json data
}

//Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
$user_name      = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$user_email     = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$country_code   = filter_var($_POST["country_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$phone_number   = filter_var($_POST["phone_number"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$subject        = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$message        = filter_var($_POST["msg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//additional php validation
if(strlen($user_name)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
    die($output);
}
if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
    die($output);
}
if(!filter_var($country_code, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){ //check for valid numbers in country code field
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in country code'));
    die($output);
}
if(!filter_var($phone_number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)){ //check for valid numbers in phone number field
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in phone number'));
    die($output);
}
if(strlen($subject)<3){ //check emtpy subject
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Subject is required'));
    die($output);
}
if(strlen($message)<3){ //check emtpy message
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
    die($output);
}

//email body
$message_body = $message."\n\n".$user_name."\nEmail : ".$user_email."\nPhone Number : (".$country_code.") ". $phone_number ;

### Attachment Preparation ###
$file_attached = false;
if(isset($_FILES['file_attach'])) //check uploaded file
{
    //get file details we need
    $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['file_attach']['tmp_name'];
    $file_name        = $_FILES['file_attach']['name'];
    $file_size        = $_FILES['file_attach']['size'];
    $file_type        = $_FILES['file_attach']['type'];
    $file_error       = $_FILES['file_attach']['error'];

    //exit script and output error if we encounter any
    if($file_error>0)
    {
        $mymsg = array( 
        1=>"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini", 
        2=>"The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form", 
        3=>"The uploaded file was only partially uploaded", 
        4=>"No file was uploaded", 
        6=>"Missing a temporary folder" ); 

        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => $mymsg[$file_error]));
        die($output); 
    }

    //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
    $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    //now we know we have the file for attachment, set $file_attached to true
    $file_attached = true;
}


if($file_attached) //continue if we have the file
{
    $boundary = md5("sanwebe"); 

    //header
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$user_email."" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

    //plain text 
    $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
    $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message_body)); 

    //attachment
    $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
    $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
    $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
    $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
    $body .= $encoded_content; 

}else{
    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$user_email.'' . "\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $body = $message_body;
}

$send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers);


if(!$send_mail)
{
    //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
    die($output);
}else{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_name .' Thank you for your email'));
    die($output);
  }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Try changing `$body = $message_body;` to `$body = htmlspecialchars($message_body);`. I think that'll do the trick.

Comment: icecub thx for response! Changed but still don't properly work.

Comment: Ye I've just noticed that your filters are already doing that job so that change is pointless. Looking into it.

Comment: I do not hide that it might be a problem . I have to remove the filters or replace the other ?

Answer (score 0):

I had te rewrite a bit of the code to get it working, but here you go. You indeed set your headers a bit wrong and forgot to set the MIME version. I've tested this one out myself and it sends the characters correctly.

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_email       = "email@gmail.com"; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here
    $from_email     = "noreply@YOUR-DOMAIN.com"; //From email address (eg: no-reply@YOUR-DOMAIN.com)

    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
            'type'=>'error',
            'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
        ));
        die($output); //exit script outputting json data
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_name      = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_email     = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $country_code   = filter_var($_POST["country_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $phone_number   = filter_var($_POST["phone_number"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $subject        = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $message        = filter_var($_POST["msg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_name)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($country_code, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){ //check for valid numbers in country code field
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in country code'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($phone_number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)){ //check for valid numbers in phone number field
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in phone number'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($subject)<3){ //check emtpy subject
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Subject is required'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($message)<3){ //check emtpy message
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }

    //email body
    $message_body = $message."\r\n\r\n".$user_name."\r\nEmail : ".$user_email."\r\nPhone Number : (".$country_code.") ". $phone_number ;

    ### Attachment Preparation ###
    $file_attached = false;
    if(isset($_FILES['file_attach'])) //check uploaded file
    {
        //get file details we need
        $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['file_attach']['tmp_name'];
        $file_name        = $_FILES['file_attach']['name'];
        $file_size        = $_FILES['file_attach']['size'];
        $file_type        = $_FILES['file_attach']['type'];
        $file_error       = $_FILES['file_attach']['error'];

        //exit script and output error if we encounter any
        if($file_error>0)
        {
            $mymsg = array( 
            1=>"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini", 
            2=>"The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form", 
            3=>"The uploaded file was only partially uploaded", 
            4=>"No file was uploaded", 
            6=>"Missing a temporary folder" ); 

            $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => $mymsg[$file_error]));
            die($output); 
        }

        //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
        $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);
        $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        //now we know we have the file for attachment, set $file_attached to true
        $file_attached = true;
    }


    if($file_attached) //continue if we have the file
    {
        $boundary = md5("sanwebe"); 

        //header
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$user_email."" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

        //plain text 
        $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
        $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message_body)); 

        //attachment
        $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
        $body .= $encoded_content; 

    }else{
        //proceed with PHP email.
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: '.$from_email."\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$user_email."\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        $body = nl2br($message_body);
    }

    $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers);


    if(!$send_mail)
    {
        //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_name .' Thank you for your email'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

Also, I've changed the code to allow for html inside the message body. If you don't want this, change

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
```

to

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
```

And

```
$body = nl2br($message_body);
```

to

```
$body = $message_body;
```

**Result:**

[image: Result of code]

Comment: What is "nl2br" in  $body = nl2br($message_body);  I copied your code for me still don't work its mean don't show letters in sent email like óżćł itp

Comment: @Miro I've edited my answer. `nl2br` simply changes `\n` to `<br />` (newline). It's not needed if you don't want to support html inside the message body. Unfortunetely I can't solve your problem when I'm unable to reproduce it. The only other solution would be to go on Teamviewer together so I can actually see what's going on over there.

Comment: @Miro I've edited my answer again. As you can see, the code I've provided works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Look below at photos.

Answer (score 0):

I copy your code +

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
```

+

```
$body = nl2br($message_body);
```

and I have this my result below i cant make it seen need 10 reputation :).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKsQ1.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3UMM.png

Comment: Never answer your own question to provide more information. Always edit your own question for that. Anyway. You shouldn't just copy those lines. You should copy my complete code as more changes have been made to it.